# Alternative to DELETE records from the Database?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-delete

I was told that we never delete records from the table, because it will be needed in future. and can I know is there any alternative than DELETE where I can DEACTIVATE the row than completely removing the row from table?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A common pattern to "soft-delete" items is to add a DateDeleted column to the table (NULL when not deleted). You can then use this column to filter out deleted items.

Comment: @Chase if your comment  were an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I delete or disable a row in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347160/should-i-delete-or-disable-a-row-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a `bit` column to your tables - call it something like `IsActive` or `IsDeleted`

When you `INSERT` data make sure that the data is marked with the correct value:

```
New record - IsActive = true
           - IsDeleted = false
```

Then when you what to make the records unavailable you will do an `UPDATE` to flag the records the opposite way:

```
Update - IsActive = false
       - IsDeleted = true
```

When you run your queries you will filter the data out according to this flag.  We implement this type of *soft delete* throughout our system and it works to hide records.

Answer (score 1):

We use the same pattern as [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) and it works pretty well.

Some pointers which may help you to implement this.

Make sure your `bit` column is non-nullable. Logically there is no reason why you wouldn't know whether the record is deleted or not, and it makes coding at easier if you don't have to worry about testing for `null`.

Also set the `bit` column to have a default of `0` and then you don't have to worry about referring to it in your insert statements. Again, logically you would never insert a deleted record, so it follows that you shouldn't have to remember to set the value to `0` when you add a record.